# Hide and show more rows of a datalist table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html-table, datalist

I have an asp datalist that is setup as follows:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlListItems" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="100%" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" ItemStyle-BorderColor="#E8E6E7" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" ItemStyle-BorderWidth="1px"
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table">
```

Within the datalist each node contains a a div with the class "divList"

I need to be able to implement something so not all nodes are shown on load and a button to load more. No server side action needs to happen, simply the ability to show hidden rows.

I have managed to get it working by hiding and then showing 10 divs at a time. Whilst this works well the table rows from the datalist are still shown and you therefore get a big gap of empty rows at the bottom of the datalist.

```
 $(function () {
    $(".divList").slice(0, 10).show(); 
    $("#load").click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".divList:hidden").slice(0, 10).fadeIn(1500);          
    });
});
```

Was hoping someone might have some suggestions on how I can implement this on the table rows rather than the divs in order to prevent the empty spacing within the datalist. Bearing in mind (as far as I know) I can't assign any id's classes to the datalist generated rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this

```
$(function(){
    var trs =  $("#dlListItems tr");
    trs.hide();
    trs.slice(0, 10).show(); 
    $("#load").click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dlListItems tr:hidden").slice(0, 10).fadeIn(1500);          
    });
});
```

First make your all Table rows in your dlListItems hidden, then get trs which you want to show as you don't want to show those rows which have hidden divs.

Comment: Amazing!! Exactly what I was after. Nice to see how ho you manipulate the tables. Thanks alot.

Comment: Maybe it's my understanding but something that is a bit weird, although we are slicing 10 rows at a time, the load more button doesn't. Sometimes it displays 3 new rows, sometimes 3 new rows and 1 column, and sometimes 4 new rows. Any ideas on what may be casuign that?

Comment: Don't worry, I worked it out. My div actually has a table inside so it's displaying these as well. Will have to try and find a way to do it differently. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function () {
  $(".divList").parent().parent().hide();
  $(".divList").parent().parent().slice(0, 5).show();
  $("#load").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(".divList:hidden").parent().parent().slice(0, 5).fadeIn(1500);
  });
});
```

As `dlListItems` is an ID of a dynamic control it can change dynamically over client side (depending upon the nesting of your controls). So I guess this would be a better approach.